# JWT token expired when Go app is installed

Tags: go, jwt, go-gin

I am working on a SAAS based product. I am using JWT method to authenticate the logged in users in the system. The product is developed on Go on the backend with gin framework for routing.

**Problem**

When a user log in then its JWT token is generated and works well. Now the user did not logged out but closed the browser tab or window. Before he is back, the go app is re-installed with install command. Now the user come back and access his account, the token is expired and he could not see any of his details.

Following is the code to generate token while login:

```
func CreateToken(user models.User, c *gin.Context) (string, error){
var ip, userAgent string
keyError := InitKeys()
if keyError != nil{
    return "", keyError
}

if values, _ := c.Request.Header["Ip"]; len(values) > 0 {
    ip = values[0]
}

if values, _ := c.Request.Header["User-Agent"]; len(values) > 0{
    userAgent = values[0]
}

token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, &jwt.MapClaims{
    "email": user.EmailId,
    "exp": time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 8760).Unix(),
    "role": user.Role,
    "name": user.FirstName+" "+user.LastName,
    "ip": ip,
    "user_agent": userAgent,
    "id": user.Id,
})
config.CurrentUserId    = user.Id
models.CurrentUser      = user

/* Sign and get the complete encoded token as a string */
tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte(config.SignKey))
return tokenString, err
```

}

```
func InitKeys()(err error){
    SignKey, err = ioutil.ReadFile(GetBasePath()+PrivateKeyPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    VerifyKey, err = ioutil.ReadFile(GetBasePath()+PublicKeyPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now to decode and match the token following function is used:

```
func ParseJWTToken(c *gin.Context){
merchantDb  := models.MerchantDatabase{ c.Keys["merchant_db"].(string) }
merchantDatabase := make(map[string]interface{})
if values, _ := c.Request.Header["Authorization"]; len(values) > 0 {
    bearer := strings.Split(c.Request.Header["Authorization"][0], "Bearer")
    bearerToken := strings.TrimSpace(bearer[1])
    _, err := merchantDb.GetSession(bson.M{"token": bearerToken})
    if err != nil{
        errMsg := "Failed: Unauthorized Access."
        response := controllers.ResponseController{
            config.FailureCode,
            config.FailureFlag,
            errMsg,
            err,
        }
        controllers.GetResponse(c, response)
        c.Abort()
    }else{

        var userAgent string
        var userAgentCheck bool

        if values, _ := c.Request.Header["User-Agent"]; len(values) > 0 {
            userAgent = values[0]
        }
        _ = config.InitKeys()
        token, err := jwt.Parse(bearerToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return config.SignKey, nil
        })
        if len (token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)) > 0{
            for key, claim := range token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims) {
                if key == "user_agent"{
                    if claim == userAgent{
                        userAgentCheck = true
                    }
                }   

                if key == "role"{
                    role = claim.(string)
                }

                if key == "id"{
                    userId = claim.(float64)
                }
                if key == "name"{
                    userName = claim.(string)
                }
            }
        }
        merchantDatabase["userid"] = userId
        merchantDatabase["role"] = role
        merchantDatabase["username"] = userName
        c.Keys = merchantDatabase
        if err == nil && token.Valid && userAgentCheck == true {
            c.Next()
        } else {
            errMsg := "Failed: Invalid Token."
            response := controllers.ResponseController{
                config.FailureCode,
                config.FailureFlag,
                errMsg,
                nil,
            }
            controllers.GetResponse(c, response)
            c.Abort()
        }
    }
}else{
    errMsg := "Failed: Unauthorized Access."
    response := controllers.ResponseController{
        config.FailureCode,
        config.FailureFlag,
        errMsg,
        "Missing Authorization Header",
    }
    controllers.GetResponse(c, response)
    c.Abort()
}
```

}

I am not able to detect what I am missing. Please look into the code and guide me what should I do in this case.

Comment: What is your question? If a token has expired - it only means that it has expired, the expiration time is in the past.

Comment: @zerkms I have set the expiration time to 1 year. The point is it expires when I re-install my go app, which is wrong because neither expiration time is in the past nor the user logged out.

Comment: "The point is it expires" --- if you set expiration time of a JWT token to one year then it would expire in one year. Otherwise please define what you mean "it expires".

Comment: Actually it is not expired but it is not validated after installing the app.

Comment: What does "not validated" mean? Which error do you get, which line of code is or is not executed?

Comment: `_, err := merchantDb.GetSession(bson.M{"token": bearerToken})` is this causing the error? Is your `merchantDb.GetSession` persistent?